# Change modal window

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I have 2 modal windows: register and login. When I click to "Sign Up" button, the modal window should change. What should I do?

This is a project link.

https://jsfiddle.net/Alienwave/0kqj7tr1/4/

```
Vue.component('signup', {
    template: '#signup-template'
})

Vue.component('login', {
    template: '#login-template',
    data() {
        return {
            loginInput: '',
            passwordInput: ''
        }
    },

    methods: {
        sendRequest(e) {
                    //code not here
        },

        changeModal() {
                        // THIS!!
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
        showLogin: true,
            showSignup: false
        }
        }
        });
```

This is login template:

```
<template id="login-template">
        <transition name="modal">
            <div class="login-mask">
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="login-container">
                        <div class="login-footer">
                            <slot name="footer">
                                <div class="change-mode">
                                    <button class="change-mode-reg" @click="">Sign up</button> <!-- THIS BUTTON SHOULD CHANGE MODAL! -->
                                </div>
                            </slot>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </transition>
    </template>
```

Register template looks the same.
I cut a big chunk.

Comment: Please add your template code

Comment: Template for the link, check it, if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use case for Vue's [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html). I would update your code as follows:

**#login-template**

```
...

<div class="login-footer">
  <slot name="footer">
    <div class="change-mode">
      <button class="change-mode-reg" @click="changeModal">Sign up</button>
      <div class="change-mode-line"></div>
    </div>
  </slot>
</div>

...
```

**login component**

```
Vue.component('login', {
  template: '#login-template',
  data() {
    return {
      loginInput: '',
      passwordInput: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendRequest(e) {
      //code not here
    },
    changeModal() {
      this.$emit('change');
    }
  }
});
```

**#app**

```
<div id="app">
  <login v-if="showLogin" @close="showLogin = false" @change="changeModal"></login>
  <signup v-if="showSignup" @close="showSignup = false"></signup>
</div>
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/voveson/o4xchzkw/16/).

(**NOTE**: it looks like you might have some other issues going on here, but this gets your modal switching issue fixed.)

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, YOU'VE BEEN VERY HELPFUL!!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept & upvote this answer if it solved your problem. Cheers!